# Decomposition of the entropy

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, logarithms, entropy

So, I'm reading about this property in the MacKay book. But I don't fully get it. Can someone explain it to me? There's this example:

> A source produces a character $x$ from the alphabet $A = \{0, 1, \ldots, 9, $a$, $b$, . . . , $z$\}$; with probability $\frac 1 3$, $x$ is a numeral $\{0, \ldots, 9\}$; with probability $\frac 1 3$, $x$ is a vowel $\{$a, e, i, o, u$\}$; and with probability $\frac 1 3$ it’s one of the $21$ consonants. All numerals are equiprobable, and the same goes for vowels and consonants. Estimate the entropy of $X$.

Solution. $\log 3 + \frac 1 3(\log 10 + \log 5 + \log 21) = \log 3 + \frac 1 3\log 1050 = \log 30$ bits.

But I don't understand how they calculate it...

Thank you.

Comment: [Here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020)'s a reference and tutorial for typesetting math on this site.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A set of $n$ equiprobable events with total probability $p$ contributes

$$
\sum_ip_i\log p_i=\sum_i\frac pn\log\frac pn=p\log\frac pn=p\log p-p\log n
$$

to the negative entropy. In your case, all three sets have total probability $p=\frac13$.

Comment: Thank you, joriki. How did you solve the summation in your answer?

Comment: @Manuel: All terms are the same, and there are $n$ of them, so it's $n$ times the summand.

Comment: What about the minus operation? I don't see it in the solution I had talked in my question. If p = 1/3 then n = ??

Comment: @Manuel: Note that I wrote down the negative entropy contribution, and that $\log\frac1x=-\log x$. As to your second question, $n$ is not determined by $p$; it's the number of equiprobable events in a set.

Answer (score 2):

This is how I assumed it was broken down. Following the preceding example in the book, we use the decomposition property by revealing $x$ gradually $-$ first we get entropy of $x \in \{\text{numeric}, \text{vowel}, \text{consonant}\}$:
$$
H(1/3, 1/3, 1/3) = \frac{1}{3}\log3 + \frac{1}{3}\log3 + \frac{1}{3}\log3 = \log3
$$
Then we find entropy of $x \in$ {0,...,9} when numeric, $x \in$ {a, e, i ,o, u} when vowel, and $x \in$ {b,c,d,f,...,z} when consonant. Entropy
$$
H(\text{numeric}) = (1/3)H(0,...,9) = (1/3)[(1/10)\log10 + ... + (1/10)\log10] = (1/3)\log10\\
H(\text{vowel}) = (1/3)H(\text{a,e,i,o,u}) = (1/3)[(1/5)\log5 + ... + (1/5)\log5] = (1/3)\log5\\
H(\text{consonant}) = (1/3)H(\text{b,c,d,f,...,z}) = (1/21)[(1/21)\log21 + ... + (1/21)\log21] = (1/3)\log21
$$
Giving the total entropy as:
$$
\log3 + \frac{1}{3}(\log10 + \log5 + \log21) = \log3 + \frac{1}{3}\log(10*5*21)
$$

Comment: Shouldn't the last $H(numeric)$ be $H(consonant)$ instead?

Comment: @cdknight yes, you're right!